# Issue in Visual Studio 2019: Limit of requests to iTunes Connect is reached?(Xamarin Project)

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin, visual-studio-2019, apple-developer-account

**Error:**

> Failed to synchronize **********.com teams with Apple Developer
>   Portal. Limit of requests to iTunes Connect is reached.

Getting this issue while adding new developer account in visual studio.
Visual Studio --> Preference--> Apple developer accounts.

visual studio for mac version- 8.3.8 (build 8):

Xcode version:11.2

Comment: Hi , welcome to so ! I have submitted this issue [here] , you also can follow it up .

Comment: Thankyou,
Can you please add that issue link ????

Comment: Okey , here is the issue link. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/823822/visual-studio-for-mac-version-838-limit-of-request.html

Answer (score 0):

This issue is fixed with the latest update of Visual studio for mac.

updated to version 8.3.10(build 2)..